# How to instantiate a model in magento2?

Tags: magento2, model

Is there a way of doing something simple as in magento2?

call function like this in magento 2,

```
$model = Mage::getModel('cms/page');
```

Comment: question  is  not clear put more details....

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Magento strictly discourages the use of ObjectManager directly. It provides service classes that abstract it away for all scenarios.

For all non-injectables (models) you have to use factory:

```
protected $pageFactory;

public function __construct(\Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory)
{
    $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
}

public function someFunc()
{
    ...
    $page = $this->pageFactory->create();
    ...
}
```

All you have to do is to ask factory of desired model in constructor. It will be automatically generated when you run Magento or compiler.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it like this:

```
$model = $this->_objectManager->create('Full\Model\Class\Name\Here');
```

but you have to make sure that the `_objectManager` member exists.

In most of the classes it should, but if it doesn't inject it in the constructor. Like this:

```
protected $_objectManager;
public function __construct(
   ...,
   \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager $objectManager,
   ....
){
    ....
    $this->_objectManager= $objectManager;
    ....
}
```

**[edit one year later]**
Even if the answer above works, it is not the best practice. For the right way of doing it see Anton's answer.

Comment: got error - Class Magento\Framework\ObjectManager does not exist

Answer (score 5):

Technically if you have an instance of the `\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager` you can call `create` of `get` and this will give you the object you desire. But it really depends on where you want to use this for as Magento 2 shifts towards [dependency injection via constructor](https://wiki.magento.com/display/MAGE2DOC/Using+Dependency+Injection).