# How to instantiate a block in magento2

Tags: magento2, blocks

Is there a simple way as in magento1 :

```
 $crumbs = Mage::app()->getLayout->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to instanciate a model in magento2?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32952/how-to-instanciate-a-model-in-magento2)

Comment: A block and a model are two different things. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: Rajeev K Tom models and blocks are totally diffrent

Answer (score 20, accepted):

---

**OUTDATED: ANSWER REFERS TO MAGENTO 2 ALPHA**

---

I wish it was that easy.
It depends on where you want to instantiate it from.
If you want to create an instance from inside an other block do it like this:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Full\Block\Class\Name\Here');
```

From inside a controller do this:

```
 $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Full\Block\Class\Name\Here');
```

From inside a model:

```
 $this->_blockFactory->createBlock('Full\Block\Class\Name\Here');
```

but here there is a catch.
you have to create a protected member on the model called `_blockFactory` and inject an instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory` in the constructor and assign it to that member var.

Something like this:

```
protected $_blockFactory;
public function __construct(
   ...,
   \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
   ....
){
    ....
    $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    ....
}
```

For instantiating a block from inside a helper it works the same as for model

Comment: the simpler the better

Comment: @Marius $toplink = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml(); use in magento 1 for magento 2 $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock(Full\Block\Class\Name\Here')->toHtml();  this give a error like this Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object how can i get toHtml()?

Comment: if you are in a controller, you don't need to inject anything for `_view`. It should be available by default, although I think it's deprecated now. I wrote this answer 1.5 years ago

Comment: can you give me hint about getBlock(..)->toHtml()?

Comment: use `createBlock` instead of `getBlock`

Comment: @Marius, how do I convert this `$layout = $this->getLayout();
$totalsBlock = $layout->createBlock('checkout/cart_totals')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/totals.phtml');
return $totalsBlock->toHtml();` ??

Comment: Calling from controller->  _view  is from the Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface rite?

Comment: @SachinS. You should not use that anymore. `_view` is deprecated now in controllers and it will soon go away,

Comment: Can i call using pagefactory object like this?  $viewPanelPageFactory=$this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $viewPanel= $viewPanelPageFactory->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')->toHtml();

Comment: Yes, you should use `resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('...')`

Answer (score 15):

To instantiate a block you have to use 
`\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface` class and its `createBlock()` method.

With an helper class you could do it with this code:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * Layout
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */
     protected $_layout;


    /**
     *
     */
     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
     ) {
         $this->_layout = $layout;
         parent::__construct($context);
     }


    /**
     * Create new block
     */
     public function getBlock() {

        $block = $this->_layout
            ->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')
            ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::helper/block.phtml');

        return $block;

     }

}
```

Then call `$helper->getBlock()` from where you need.