# How to call a model method from controller in Magento2

Tags: model, controllers, magento2

I have a model with namespace `Demo\HelloWorld\Model\Customer` and model have a function `demo()` print "*Hello World !*".

How to call function `demo()` from Controller with namespace `Demo\HelloWorld\Controller\Index` ?

I try example [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32952/how-to-instantiate-a-model-in-magento2?lq=1) but not working.

> Recoverable Error : Argument 1 passed to
>   Demo\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must be an
>   instance of \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager, instance of
>   Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context given

Comment: I added. tks @RajeevKTomy

Comment: @PaW You added your answer with your question itself. That is not what I intended.You should put that as answer, you can find a button "add an answer" below. Paste your answer in that text area and click on that button :)

Comment: Answer:

$this->_objectManager->get('Full\Model\Class\Name\Here'); (as getSingleton() in Magento 1.x) or

$this->_objectManager->create('Full\Model\Class\Name\Here'); ( as getModel() in Magento 1.x).

Thanks @RajeevKTomy for advice !

Comment: @PaW Dont worry I did that for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The object manager is not the correct way to do this. Use dependency injection via the constructor whenever possible.

You are getting that error because your controller extends another class, but you are not following the parent class's constructor, or you did not clear the cache.

You have not provided your code, but I assume your controller extends `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`. If you open that, you'll see the constructor signature for that class is:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
) {
    // ...
}
```

You're getting the error because Magento is trying to inject a Context object, and you're asking for a Customer. To inject your model, *your* class constructor needs to look like this:

```
protected $customer;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Demo\HelloWorld\Model\Customer $customer
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Demo\HelloWorld\Model\Customer $customer
) {
    $this->customer = $customer;

    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Make that change, then flush the Magento cache (or folder var/cache), and then it should work.

**Note:** This is assuming your Customer class is injectable. If it's loaded from the database, you need to inject CustomerFactory instead, and then call `$customer = $this->customerFactory->create()`.

Answer (score 3):

To begin, I would follow this tutorial https://www.ashsmith.io/2014/12/simple-magento2-controller-module/ to create a simple controller to add some content. From there, I added

Demo/Simple/Model/Customer.php

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Simple\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Object;

class Customer extends Object
{
    public function sayHi(){
        echo "HEYHO";
    }
}
```

And then added a new dependency via Constructor injection in the Controller:

```
\Demo\Simple\Model\Customer $customer
```

So now my Demo/Controller/Index/Index.php looks like:

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Simple\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
     protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Demo\Model\Customer
     */
        protected $customer;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory     resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
         \Demo\Simple\Model\Customer $customer
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customer = $customer;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Default customer account page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->customer->sayHi();
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

And, after clearing all caches, this is echoing "HEYHO" at the top of my page.

Comment: Your code helped me but there is an error in model file (**Demo/Simple/Model/Customer.php**): `class Customer extends \Magento\Framework\Object;` this class does not exist (Magento 2.1.2)
I've used `class Customer extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel` and all worked fine

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**in Model/Method/customFree.php**

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Payment\Paypal\Model\Method;
/**
 * Free payment method
 * @method \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentMethodExtensionInterface getExtensionAttributes()
 */
class customFree extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Free
{


    /**
     * Check whether method is enabled in config
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote|null $quote
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAvailableInConfig2()
    {
        echo "  learning magento2  ";
    }
}
```

**In controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Payment\Paypal\Controller\Index;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action as controllerAction; 
class Index extends controllerAction {  

     protected $customer;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Demo\HelloWorld\Model\Customer $customer
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Payment\Paypal\Model\Method\customFree $customer
    ) {
        $this->customer = $customer;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the content of the response
     */
    public function execute() {
        $this->getResponse()->appendBody('Hello world');
        $this->customer->isAvailableInConfig2();
    }
}
```

**in etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="Payment" frontName="custompaypal">
            <module name="Payment_Paypal" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**in browser**

localhost/magento/custompaypal

[image]