# PHP Fatal error: main(): Failed opening required 'app/Mage.php' Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I'm trying to add a thumbnail image to the view order page in the account section with the following code but it doesn't do anything:

```
<td>
    <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="" />
</td>
```

I get the following error:
PHP Fatal error:  main(): Failed opening required 'app/Mage.php'

```
require(__DIR__ . '/app/Mage.php');
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Magento 2, **don't try to use** `Mage::getModel` or `Mage::helper`. They are Magento 1 ways. In your case, you can follow [this guide](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106556/how-to-display-product-image-in-sales-order-view-page/) to get thumbnail image on order view page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no more exist Mage class in magento2

You can use Model class only through objectManager or Factory method.

How to instantiate a model in magento2, you can take help from here: [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32952/how-to-instantiate-a-model-in-magento2)